# How to make deployed version of a cpprestsdk application as small as possible?

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I've developed an application using [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk), now I'm going to deploy it. I want just a standalone executable, so I tried to install cpprestsdk statically using vcpkg. After that, when I link to cpprestsdk statically, even the small code like bellow is 3 MB in size which is very big for my conditions.

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>

using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features

int main()
{
    http_client client(U("http://google.com"));
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea? Instead of linking to the static library of cpprestsdk, Isn't it better to use cpprestsdk source? I mean try to resolve compile-time and link-time errors using the smallest possible set of files of cpprestsdk?
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: You *are* compiling in release mode, right? Many linker optimizations are turned off in Debug mode.

Comment: @Botje Of course.